# How to redirect users to their specified page after logging in?

Tags: php, if-statement, authentication, session-variables, forms-authentication

I've modified the login file to redirect user to their specified page. But my code simply redirect every user to the first option(rd). Users under pd department are directed to rd page. My code is as below. Note: Please ignore SQL injection comments if there's any vulnerability... 
My db table, aside from names, includes the columns access level (admin & user) department (rd & pd).

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
 session_start();
                     }
include_once("connections/connection.php");
$con = connection();

if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

$user = $con->query($sql) or die ($con->error);
$row = $user->fetch_assoc();
$total =$user->num_rows;

if($total > 0 AND $department=rd){
$_SESSION['UserLogin'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['Access'] = $row['access'];
$_SESSION['Fname'] = $row['fname'];
$_SESSION['Lname'] = $row['lname'];
$_SESSION['Department'] = $row['department'];

echo $_SESSION['UserLogin'];
echo header("Location: index_rd.php");}

else  if($total > 0 AND $department=pd){
$_SESSION['UserLogin'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['Access'] = $row['access'];
$_SESSION['Fname'] = $row['fname'];
$_SESSION['Lname'] = $row['lname'];
$_SESSION['Department'] = $row['department'];

echo $_SESSION['UserLogin'];
echo header("Location: index_proc.php");}

else{
echo "No user found.";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are also getting errors?

`$department=rd` is an assignment (to an undefined constant!).

`$department == 'rd'` is a valid comparison.

Also, based on your code, `$department` is undefined. You'll want to use `$row['department']` instead. And seriously, crank your PHP error reporting up a notch or two, it'll help you heaps. ;)

Comment: you're right! i got the errors you've mentioned. I used $department == 'rd' and $row['department'] instead and it works!  The users were directed to their specific page. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes i tried but unfortunately i received this comment from this website: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."